# ContextMenu open div to link attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, contextmenu

"This" not work...

Script home page:
http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="click" IDMenu="menu01">click</div>
<div class="menu01" style="display:none;">this is a menu</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(function() {
$('.click').contextMenu('.'+ $(this).attr("IDMenu"));
});
```

Comment: what is the error on console?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi returns no error but does not work

Comment: @spark87 create a fiddle please

Comment: In your code 'this' refers to document. use $('.click').attr("IDMenu") instead of  $(this).attr("IDMenu")

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uqL7f54e/4/

Comment: @spark87 updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uqL7f54e/10/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Correct, but I need it to be dynamic as there will be many menu for this I used the attribute

Comment: @spark87 see this http://jsfiddle.net/uqL7f54e/12/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Almost perfect. remains a problem: if I click first on the first and then on the second stay open both menus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61029/discussion-between-spark87-and-anoop-joshi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because `this` in that context refers to `document` which might not have attribute `IDMenu`. Do this instead:

```
$(function() {
   var elem = $('.click'); // cache the element
   elem.contextMenu('.'+ elem.attr("IDMenu")); // reuse it again here
});
```

It would be better if you would avoid creating custom attributes and instead go for `data-*` attributes.

Updated code as per OP's requirement

```
$(function() {
    $(".click").each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.contextMenu('.' + elem.attr("IDMenu"));
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqL7f54e/12/)

Comment: Hi, not work... http://jsfiddle.net/uqL7f54e/8/

Comment: @Anoop Joshi thanks for the edit mate.

Comment: @spark87 check out now

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Almost perfect. remains a problem: if I click first on the first and then on the second stay open both menus

Comment: @spark87 see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uqL7f54e/16/